# Get all values from tableViewCell from TextFields

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I want to get all **values** from `TableViewCell` with `TextFields`, but i do not understand how i can do it by clicking on button.

And I can add new row if I click on button `Add`. So i can make as many rows as I want.

My code here:

```
struct Section {
    let title: String
    var rows: [String]
}

class SettingsScheduleAndPricesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var hall: Halls?

    var sections = [Section]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sections = [Section(title: "Day of week", rows: []),
                    Section(title: "Second section", rows: [""]),
                    Section(title: "Third section", rows: [""])]
    }

    // MARK: - TableView
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].rows.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            ...
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let hourlyRateCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "hourlyRateCell", for: indexPath) as! SettingsHourlyRateCell
            return hourlyRateCell
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section].title
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let frame: CGRect = tableView.frame
        if section == 0 {
            let headerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height))
            headerView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)
            return headerView
        } else if section == 1 {
            let addButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: frame.size.width - 50, y: 0, width: 50, height: 30))
            addButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            addButton.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2588235438, green: 0.7568627596, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
            addButton.setTitle(NSLocalizableAdd, for: .normal)
            addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SettingsScheduleAndPricesViewController.addHourlyRate(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            let headerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height))
            headerView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)
            headerView.addSubview(addButton)
            return headerView
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }

    @IBAction func saveBarButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        // here I want to get all values from my Cell from my TextFields

    }

    @objc func addHourlyRate(sender: UIButton) {
        let newRow = ""
        append(row: newRow, in: 1)
    }

    func append(row : String, in section: Int) {
        let insertionIndex = sections[section].rows.count
        sections[section].rows.append(row)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: insertionIndex, section: section)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}

class SettingsHourlyRateCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var rubHourTF: UITextField!
}
```

My example from simulator:

[image]

In my example me need to get `first`, `second` and `third` string texts from three rows. And append in empty `array` or just print in `console`.

In method `@IBAction func saveBarButtonPressed(_ sender: Any)`.

I couldn't find anything that could help me.

Comment: In your [previous answer (accepted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377432/cant-insert-new-row-in-tableview) I suggested to use a custom struct as data source. Why do you go back to ugly multiple arrays? The most efficient way is to use a class (instead of a struct) which has reference semantics and pass the row item to the cell. In the cell update the properties in the data source item. But you can't do that with multiple arrays.

Comment: @vadian I made corrections, thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextFields in TableView cells can be tricky. First, use the data model and reloadData() instead of insertRows(at:) like this:

```
@objc func addHourlyRate(sender: UIButton) {
    let newRow: String = ""
    secondRowText.append(newRow)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Now, set the text in the cells, and tag the UITextField with the row number in cellForRowAt() like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let hourlyRateCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "hourlyRateCell", for: indexPath) as! SettingsHourlyRateCell
   hourlyRateCell.rubHourTF.text = secondRowText[indexPath.row]
   hourlyRateCell.rubHourTF.tag = indexPath.row              
   return hourlyRateCell

}
```

Next, use UITextFieldDelegate to keep track of any changes in the text fields, something like:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
     let tableRow = textField.tag
     secondRowText[tableRow] = textField.text
}
```

Notice how the textField tag that was set in cellForRow() is now used to know which row the textField is at in the table.

Comment: Where do I get `indexPath.row` in`textFieldDidEndEditing`? Or maybe you mean replace `indexPath.row` on `tableRow`?

Comment: but it not helped me :(

Comment: Yes, substitute 'tableRow' for 'indexPath.row' in textFieldDidEndEditing (edit submitted). indexPath.row is saved as 'rubHourTF.tag' when the cell is created, then used as secondRowText array index to set the text value in the data source in textFieldDidEndEditing.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe my method will help someone, but I still managed to do it this way. I just add in my `button` this code:

```
@IBAction func saveBarButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let countRowsOne = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 1)
        for index in 0...countRowsOne {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 1)
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? SettingsHourlyRateCell {
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a delegate protocol for your cell

```
protocol cellDelegate {
func buttonClicked(textFieldText: String)}
```

and make a variable of your protocol in your cell

```
var delegate: cellDelegate?
```

then on button click event call the method from the variable

```
delegate?.buttonClicked(textFieldText: "string you got from textField")
```

and in your **table view cellForRowAt indexPath** method set delegate of the cell like this: `cell.delegate = self`

Comment: I don't understand how I'll get three texts from my three TextFields

Comment: in diffrent cells?

Comment: yes, if you look my image, I have three row and me need get all three text from rows in section 1

Comment: you can make a static variable of string array and append it from your cell in textfield textChange event if textfield.text != nil

Answer (score -1):

No Tag is needed

```
@IBAction func saveBarButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    var array = NSMutableArray()
    for subview in self.tableView.subViews {
         if subView.isKind(of: String(describing: SettingsHourlyRateCell.self)) {
            for sView in subview {
               if sView.isKind(of: String(describing: UITextField.self)) {   
                 array.add(sView.text)
            }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: not helped me, error in line `self.tableViewController.view.subViews`, i can't apply this